# What object should my java function return if its return value is one of two possible objects known only at runtime?

Tags: java, object, subclass, superclass

I have a super class called PageObject, and then two subclasses called AlphaPage and BetaPage that inherit the PageObject. 
A function "selectPage()" will return one of these pages, but the specific page to return will only be known at runtime.

What should the function's return object be, then, that will avoid having to cast one of the subclasses to the function call's return val?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The caller will *have* to cast if they want the specific type, given that the information is only known at execution time. You should return `PageObject`, basically.

Of course, if the caller doesn't need anything specific to `AlphaPage` or `BetaPage` - if they can just use methods (possibly abstract) declared on `PageObject`, then there'll be no need to cast. That would be the ideal - use polymorphism to handle the differences. It really depends on what the caller needs to do though.

Answer (score 1):

Ideally I would suggest defining a common `Interface` that will be implemented by both `AlphaPage` and `BetaPage`, as both would be having lot of common behavior.

Alternately you can declare an abstract class (maybe `PageObject` class in your case) which could implement any common code that your pages may have.

So my answer is the return type should be a common super type (An interface or Abstract Class).

Answer (score 0):

you can define an interface and specify which functions a Page should offer and then your Page-Classes will implement this interface thus providing desired functionality

```
public interface pageable {

pageable selectPage();
    ...
}



PageObject implements pageable {

    pageable selectPage(){
       ...
    }

...
```